# Rviz robot model will not open via script

Tags: ros, python, rviz, bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Without bash and python script: master and rviz works successfully

When I run "roscore" in first terminal. Master runs successfully

```
process[master]: started with pid [4355] ROS_MASTER_URI=http://userid:11311/
```

New terminal I type in "roslaunch /home/userid/catkin_ws/src/robot/launch/robot.launch". This basically open RVIZ with the robot model in grid successfully

Above steps are implemented as follows in bash and python script and it does NOT work.

##bashscript.sh

```
   source ~/.bashrc
    
 python pythonscript.py
```

##pythonscript.py

```
def init():
    os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"pwd; roslaunch /home/userid/catkin_ws/src/robot/launch/robot.launch; exec bash\"'")

if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    init()
```

This fails. RVIZ opens with a white blob in center on grid NOT the robot model. and left hand panel it says robot model error. status error.

Why rviz wouldn't work with script?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265014/rviz-robot-model-will-not-open-via-script/) by [vrosuser](https://answers.ros.org/users/30434/vrosuser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why would you want to start rviz from inside a python file at all?

It's hard to tell if that fits your functionality, but maybe you can use a ros launchfile.

You could then launch your executable as well as the other launchfile like this:

```
<launch>
    <include file="$(find robot)/launch/demo.launch"/>
    <node name="mynode" pkg="mypkg" type="pythonscipt />
</launch>
```

To get this to work you need to define "pythonscript" as an executable in your CMakeList.txt of course.

---

Originally posted by [Felix_N](https://answers.ros.org/users/30725/felix_n/) with karma: 115 on 2017-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vrosuser](https://answers.ros.org/users/30434/vrosuser/) on 2017-06-29**:
My plan was to include all launch cmds in python script. so user will have to simply run one python script, instead of doing a roslaunch. I will try the solution you have proposed.

I would still like to understand the theory as to why the method I have implemented not work.?